# JS slider not showing in ie7

Tags: php, wordpress, slider

I have a javascript slider for my site, which works for all browsers except for ie7. I figured out why the images are not showing.

Im using the previous version of the [Marco Folio](http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/animated_fullscreen_background_image_slideshow.html) background slider.

I would appreciate some help with this, as this seems to be the only serious issue with my site right now.

Here is the site: [doctorstvnetwork.com](http://www.doctorstvnetwork.com)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post a link to the website? Does IE7 shows any error?

Comment: Chris, sorry about that. I updated my post. Let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this is not the answer you're looking for, but thought I'd post this anyhow.

Your slider images are loading in real-time, causing a delay in seeing the image the first time the slider switches to them. You can preload the images in the background with this snippet:

```
/*
 *   preload images function
 */

(function($) {
  var cache = [];
  // Arguments are image paths relative to the current page.
  $.preLoadImages = function() {
    var args_len = arguments.length;
    for (var i = args_len; i--;) {
      var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
      cacheImage.src = arguments[i];
      cache.push(cacheImage);
    }
  }
})(jQuery)

// call the function in doc ready
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.preLoadImages("/path/to/image1.png", "/path/to/image2.png");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Todd, I'll try this out. I appreciate your input.